# Spring boot 2 + Microsoft AD authentication + userPassword attribute not found

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to authenticate user against Microsoft AD using spring boot 2.1.9.RELEASE. I am able to find the user dn from the AD, but it's not authenticating the user and getting a null pointer exception.

My WebSecurityConfig Code

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        // auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());

        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("CN={0},OU=Users")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})").contextSource()
                .url(AD_URL)
                .managerDn(AD_USERNAME).managerPassword(AD_PASSWORD).and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");

    }
```

ERROR LOG

```
w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Request is to process authentication
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider     : Processing authentication request for user: <username>
o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://<companyname>.com:389/dc=<companyname>,dc=com'
o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch      : Searching for user '<username>', with user search [ searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={0})', searchBase: '', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://<companyname>.com:389/dc=<companyname>,dc=com'
o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Searching for entry under DN 'dc=<companyname>,dc=com', base = '', filter = '(sAMAccountName={0})'
o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Found DN: CN=<User Full Name>,OU=Users,OU=HM Bangalore,OU=Office Locations
o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Ignoring PartialResultException
.s.s.l.a.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator : Performing LDAP compare of password attribute 'userPassword' for user 'CN=<User Full Name>,OU=Users,OU=HM Bangalore,OU=Office Locations'
o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@456cde20
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.LdapShaPasswordEncoder.extractPrefix(LdapShaPasswordEncoder.java:193) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.LdapShaPasswordEncoder.matches(LdapShaPasswordEncoder.java:162) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.LdapShaPasswordEncoder.matches(LdapShaPasswordEncoder.java:158) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.isPasswordAttrCompare(PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.java:121) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.authenticate(PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.java:109) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:187) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
.
.
.
```

On further investigating the error log, I found that the below code tries to get the encoded password from the user object, but my passwordAttributeName "userPassword" is not there in the user object

org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.isPasswordAttrCompare(PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.java:121)

```
.
.
.
    private boolean isPasswordAttrCompare(DirContextOperations user, String password) {
        String passwordAttrValue = getPassword(user);
        return passwordEncoder.matches(password, passwordAttrValue);
    }

    private String getPassword(DirContextOperations user) {
        Object passwordAttrValue = user.getObjectAttribute(this.passwordAttributeName);
        if (passwordAttrValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (passwordAttrValue instanceof byte[]) {
            return new String((byte[]) passwordAttrValue);
        }
        return String.valueOf(passwordAttrValue);
    }
.
.
.
```

Not sure why i am unable to get the encoded password from AD. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Active Directory does not use the normal "userPassword" password but rather the "[unicodePwd](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/UnicodePwd)".

Further, as with many LDAP server implementations, Microsoft Active Directory **will not** return a value for the password attribute.

Finally, performing a LDAP compare on password is a poor practice and **should not** be utilized as some of the built in features such as Password Expiration and Intruder Detection may be bypassed when performing a Compare Request on the userPassword attribute.
You should always perform a bind operation against LDAP.

Comment: There is a [`userPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f3adda9f-89e1-4340-a3f2-1f0a6249f1f8) attribute, but it really is just an alias for `unicodePwd`. But you're right in that there is absolutely no way to retrieve the password.

Comment: @GabrielLuci - As I recall, this requires setting the dsHeuristics value and is not the default behavior. Right?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/e5899be4-862e-496f-9a38-33950617d2c5), you're right. The default is disabled for AD DS, but the default is enabled for AD LDS. I assume we're talking about AD DS here.